# How can I make a div follow a curved trajectory?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I am currently making a lil web game in my free time and I have some code that draws 'rock particles' whenever the rock gets clicked.

You can view the game here and click on the rock so you have a better idea of what I want: [github pages link here](https://isyn.github.io/More-Ore/)

The current code I have is this:

```
Game.drawRockParticles = (event) => {

    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('particle')
    let x = event.clientX
    let y = event.clientY

    div.style.left = x + 'px'
    div.style.top = y + 'px'

    let particleY = y
    let particleX = x

    let randomNumber = Math.random()
    let randomSign = Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1

    let particleUp = setInterval(() => {
      particleX += randomNumber * randomSign
      particleY -= 1
      div.style.top = particleY + 'px'
      div.style.left = particleX + 'px'
    }, 10)

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(particleUp)

      let particleDown = setInterval(() => {
        particleX += randomNumber * randomSign / 2
        particleY += 1.5
        div.style.top = particleY + 'px'
        div.style.left = particleX + 'px'
      }, 10)

      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(particleDown)
        if (div.parentNode) div.parentNode.removeChild(div)
      }, 1000)
    }, 100)

    s('body').append(div)
  }
}
```

To save you some time on what this block of code does, when you click on the rock, it generates a particle. The code then determines whether the particle should fall left or right. Then the particle goes up a bit then falls down according to the direction determined beforehand.

I am pretty sure this is extremely inefficient and slows down my game.

I believe I can achieve this sort of this with just CSS transforms with cubic bezier? Im not entirely sure. Just looking for some other possible ideas for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look up projectile motion for this.

Comment: ...or motion paths

Comment: Never heard of those. Will look into it

Comment: Have to agree with @Paulie_D that motion paths are an awesome experimental concept -but- with very [limited support](https://caniuse.com/#search=motion-path) yet, but for more reliable support I'd look into something like [greensock](https://greensock.com/path-animation)

Comment: @ChrisW. I see that the path is predetermined. But for my case, I need it to be somewhat randomized. Is that still possible?

Comment: Ya you might poke around their site and look at the GSAP stuff for TweenLite/Max etc, you can feed it whatever dynamically but unfortunately it's not a free library.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas using a multiple transform.

To make this random using CSS, use some CSS variables and set them via JS

```css
.test {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    animation: path 4s infinite linear;
}

.test:nth-child(2) {
    animation: path2 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes path {
    from {transform:  translate(0px, 0px)  rotate(180deg) translateX(50px);}
    to {transform:  translate(100px, 0px) rotate(360deg) translateX(50px) ;}

}

@keyframes path2 {
    from {transform:  translate(0px, 0px)  rotate(180deg) translateX(50px);}
    to {transform:  translate(50px, 60px) rotate(360deg) translateX(80px) ;}

}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```